# Python - extract word from specific position in text (e.g line 3, second word)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, text, split

input.txt looks like this:

```
A 
B C D
E F G
H I J
```

Aim: grab F by pointing at the line and column. I can fetch the line using the code below. But how do I only select the second word? Using .splitlines somehow?

```py
line = []
with open (path, 'rt') as input:
    for mylines in input:
        line.append(mylines)
print(line[3])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read line by line, then split the desired line and get the desired column. This does not perform error checking to make sure the column exists, but does perform error checking in the case that input file has fewer lines than the desired row.

```py
line = []
desired_row = 3
desired_col = 2
value = None
with open (path, 'rt') as input:
    current_line = 1
    for mylines in input:
        if current_line == desired_row:
            value = mylines.split()[desired_col - 1]
            break
        current_line += 1
print(value)
```

Comment: Thanks (also for formatting my question)! I'm getting 'None' as output for this example. something wrong with the .split line?

Comment: Trying printing ```mylines.split()``` and see what happens

Comment: Hmm, so     print(mylines.split())     and print(mylines.split()[desired_col - 1]) works.     print(value) is None. How come?

Comment: Solved. I didn't use 'current_line += 1'. ops.